# Is there any function to pass onClick function to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I create a button to avoid generating double number with same values, and I create when one user click on it to show him and to other users that values is in saving process so I can avoid that double values.
But when I try to catch that on server side controller, it showed me in `Inspect element->Network->Status 302 -> POST -> FILE (GenerateCodes)`.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateCodes", "Codes", FormMethod.Post))
   {
  <div class="box-header">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
  <!--Disable button for about 3 second after click button-->
   <button type="submit" id="ok"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="return DisplayProgressMessage(this, 'Saving...');">Generate</button>
   <script>
   function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
   $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
   $(ctl).text(msg);
   return true;
   }
   </script>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  }
```

My Codes.cs controller.

```
    protected void DisplayProgressMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Something
    Response.Write("DD");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method name in your controller needs to be "GenerateCodes" to match the action in the Html.BeginForm() helper method. Also the parameters in the method need to either be the model from your .cshtml view or no parameters if you are not working with a model in the view. Finally you need a HttpPost attribute on the method in the controller to let it know you are posting a form to this method.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GenerateCodes()
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I already have defined `GenerateCodes` in my controller, I use it for save values of generated codes in database and other stuffs.